# Regex for at least a certain number of digits in a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

When a user submits a form I need to make sure that the input contains at least a minimum number of digits. The problem is that I don't know what format the input will be in. The digits likely won't be in a row, and might be separated by letters, punctuation, spaces, etc. I don't care about the rest of the string.

I'd like to check this with a RegularExpressionValidator but I'm not quite sure how to write the regex.

I guess this would be similar to a phone number regex, but a phone number at least has some common formats.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following will match an input string containing at least `n` digits:

```
Regex.IsMatch(input, @"(\D*\d){n}");
```

where `n` is an integer value.

A short explanation:

- `\D*` matches zero or more non-digit chars (`\D` is a short hand for `[^0-9]` or `[^\d]`);
- so `\D*\d` matches zero or more non-digit chars followed by a digit;
- and `(\D*\d){n}` groups, and repeats, the previous `n` times.

Comment: i pondered this for a while and reached the conclusion that it couldn't be done without a repetitive pattern. but once you see it it's strikingly obvious. elegant! +1

Comment: @David, thanks! @annakata, I've added more explanation to my post.

Comment: Thanks, Bart! I have to agree with what David said. Nice solution :)

Comment: @Bart, is there a way to make this take in a minimum instead of a set number? I tried replacing `{n}` with `{n,}`, but that breaks it. It starts counting the non-digits as well.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the .NET regex engine, but I'd say `{n,}` should worl as well. AFAIK, `@"(\D*\d){n}"` causes the engine to look for **at least** `n` occurrences of `(\D*\d)` so it wouldn't make any difference to use either `{n}` or `{n,}`. Sorry I can't be of any more assistance!

Answer (score 3):

I would approach it something like this:

```
Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^([^0-9]*[0-9]){10}.*$");
```

In words, this would search for 10 digits, each of which are surrounded by 0 or more characters.  Since the .* are greedy, any additional digits would be matched by them as well.

Anyway, check out http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx  It can be really hard to write a regular expression without something to test against.

Comment: +1, thanks for the help. I've been using regexpal.com, but that one looks a little better. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

in order to have at least n digits, you need to use following regex:

(\D*\d){n,}

Regex (\D*\d){n} will match exactly n digits.

Regards, Karlo.