# Regex for american phone numbers that will also pickup (123) space and 123 dot

Tags: .net, regex, match, phone-number

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

I've got this.

```
1?\s*-?\s*(\d{3}|\(\s*\d{3}\s*\))\s*-?\s*\d{3}\s*-?\s*\d{4}
```

It is matching a lot of the phone numbers, but it's not catching these two:

(123) 456-7890  or 123.456.7890

Comment: My eyes, they are bleeding... (Don't use such a spam-filled title, you're not trying to SEO your question! It just looks like spam)

Comment: Why don't you try understanding what you're doing? :)

Comment: @cyperpine do you actualy care? There are so many way to write a phone number that you should not validate it. What about extensions number? Or a small note like "(555) 555-5555 ask for Tim"?

Comment: I'm trying to scrape them out of a documents. Don't care about extensions, but If I can have them great. thanks.

Comment: Just one place to look http://www.regexlib.com

Answer (score 0):

Awhile back I asked a question about [a regex for a certain number of digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238355/regex-that-looks-for-a-certain-number-of-digits-in-a-string) in a string. The answer gave me this regex `(\D*\d){10}{n}`.

I've actually used this for phone number validation since then. I do not care what format they give me a phone number in, as long as it contains 10 digits. If all you care about is that you get the area code + phone number, then this may work for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simplified version of your original regex that should do what you are asking for.

```
1?[\s-(.]*?\d{3}[ -).]*?\d{3}[ -.]*?\d{4}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of monsters
Capture groups 1,2,3 hold the parts of the phone number. This is a bare bones validation.
Anything more and it gets like godzilla.

Area code not required
`/^(?:\s*(?:1(?=(?:.*\d.*){10}$)\s*[.-]?\s*)?(?:\(?\s*(\d{3}|)\s*\)?\s*[.-]?))\s*(\d{3})\s*[.-]?\s*(\d{4})$/`

Area code required
`/^(?:\s*(?:1(?=(?:.*\d.*){10}$)\s*[.-]?\s*)?(?:\(?\s*(\d{3})\s*\)?\s*[.-]?))\s*(\d{3})\s*[.-]?\s*(\d{4})$/`

The code sample (in Perl)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $rxphone = qr/
^
  (?:                         # Area code group (optional)
     \s*
     (?:
          1 (?=(?:.*\d.*){10}$)     # "1" (optional), must be 10 digits after it
         \s* [.-]?\s*
     )?
     (?: 
        \(?\s* (\d{3}|) \s*\)?      # Capture 1, 3 digit area code (optional)
        \s* [.-]?                   # ---  (999 is ok, so is 999)
     )
  )                           # End area code group
  \s*
  (\d{3})                     # The rest of phone number
  \s*
  [.-]?
  \s*
  (\d{4})
$
/x;

my %phonenumbs = (
 1 => '(123-456-7890',
 2 => '123.456-7890',
 3 => '456.7890',
 4 => '4567890',
 5 =>'(123) 456-7890',
 6 => '1 (123) 456-7890',
 7 => '11234567890',
 8 => ' (123) 4565-7890',
 9 => '1123.456-7890',
 w => '1-456-7890',
);

for my $key ( sort keys %phonenumbs)
{
    if ($phonenumbs{$key} =~ /$rxphone/) {
       print "#$key =>  '$1' '$2' '$3'\n";
    } else {
       print "#$key => not a valid phone number: '$phonenumbs{$key}' \n";
    }
}
__END__
```

Output
`#1 =>  '123' '456' '7890'`
`#2 =>  '123' '456' '7890'`
`#3 =>  '' '456' '7890'`
`#4 =>  '' '456' '7890'`
`#5 =>  '123' '456' '7890'`
`#6 =>  '123' '456' '7890'`
`#7 =>  '123' '456' '7890'`
`#8 => not a valid phone number: ' (123) 4565-7890'`
`#9 =>  '123' '456' '7890'`
`#w => not a valid phone number: '1-456-7890'`